# Why basic example in mobx with react createContext don't have default value?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, mobx, mobx-react

[Here](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#using-external-state-in-observer-components) inside "using React context" tab you can see:

```
const TimerContext = createContext<Timer>()
```

But actually it will not work, because

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
>
> index.d.ts(419, 9): An argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided.

If I do something like this:

```
const TimerContext = createContext<Timer | null>(null);
```

then I should check for null in places where I use context (for example `useContext()?.someValue`), which is also looks not good.

So what it is the right approach?